# Google Kickstart Round C: Stable Wall, Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, c++11, graph

This is the link to the problem [here](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff43/00000000003379bb)
We have to tell the order in which the letters(like bricks) have to be laid in order for the wall to be stable. ie; for example if the input is 
ZOAAMM
ZOAOMM
ZOOOOM
ZZZZOM
Then if I lay 'A's first then they will fall to the ground since in order to lay the letter 'A' I need to lay the letters 'Z' and 'O' first.
If I lay all O's first then they will also fall on the ground since some of the O's depend on the 'Z' below to be laid first.
The answer for the above is 'ZOMA' or 'ZOAM' both are valid answers. If it's not possible then we should print -1.
What I did in my code is that I first made a graph. For the example above, the graph will be O-> A since A depends on O. O->M since M also depends on O. Z->O since O depends on Z. 
Then if there is a cycle in the graph then that means it is not possible to lay the wall so I print -1
If there is no cycle then the answer exists, and to get the answer I do a topological sort.

All the example test cases passed, but when I submit, I get a wrong answer. I don't know which test case could be failing. Can you let me know any case which my code is failing for please.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int>adj[26]; // adjacency list to store the graph
int n,m;        // n rows each with a string of size m
string s[30];
bool vis[26];   //for topological sort
int visited[26];//for cycle detection
stack <char> mystack;
bool flag = 0;
void cycledfs(int node) // returns -1 if cycle detected
{
  if(visited[node] == -1)
  {
      flag = 1;
      return;
  }

  visited[node] = -1;

  for(int i = 0; i < adj[node].size(); i++)
  {
      if(visited[adj[node][i]] != 1)
      {
          cycledfs(adj[node][i]);
      }
  }
  visited[node] = 1;
}
void dfs(int node)  // if cycle is not detected we do the topological sorting
{
    
    if(!vis[node])
    {
        vis[node] = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < adj[node].size(); i++)
        {
            if(!vis[adj[node][i]])
                dfs(adj[node][i]);

        }
        mystack.push(node+'A');
    }
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n>>m;
        set <char> t; // set to store all the unique letters which are my vertices of the graph
        for(int i = 0; i <n; i++)
        {
            cin>>s[i];
            for(int j = 0; s[i][j]!='\0';j++)
                t.insert(s[i][j]);

            if(i)
            {
                for(int j = 0; s[i][j]!='\0';j++)//to check if the brick above me is different from me. Also making sure no duplicates in the graph.
                {
                    auto it = find(adj[s[i][j]-'A'].begin(), adj[s[i][j]-'A'].end(), (s[i-1][j]-'A'));
                    if(((s[i][j]-'A') != (s[i-1][j]-'A')) &&(it==adj[s[i][j]-'A'].end()))
                        adj[s[i][j]-'A'].push_back((s[i-1][j]-'A'));
                }

            }
        }
        //initializing stuff
        flag = 0;
        memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));
        memset(vis, 0, sizeof(vis));
         
        for(char i: t)//CYCLE CHECKING
        {
          //cout<<(i-'A')<<"\n";
          if(visited[i-'A'] == 0)
               cycledfs(i-'A');
          if(flag)
            break;
        }
        if(flag)
            cout<<"-1\n";
       
        else  //doing topological sort if no cycle
        {
            string result ="";
            for(char x: t)
                dfs(x-'A');
            while(!mystack.empty())
            {
                char ans = mystack.top();
                result.push_back(ans);
                mystack.pop();
            }
            cout<<result<<"\n";

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) //clearing adj list
                adj[i].clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: The coding contest is over. I read all the solution analysis and other peoples code. Still can't figure it out. I need some help please.

Comment: OK, lets start general advice to start you on getting a feeling for code and possible traps: 1 Why are you including "<bits/stdc++.h>"?

Comment: 2 Avoid global variables.

Comment: 3 Use selfexplaining variable names.

Comment: 4 Init variables, especially those which you are reading input into. In case reading fails.

Comment: Oh Goodness me! The output format! Noooooo! I Forgot to put the unique, special and beautiful output format of Case #  1:

Comment: I got it! It's working! Should I delete this question since I don't think this question will not be beneficial to stackoverflow? Well, at least someone will remember to follow the output format? :)

Comment: It's a a bit worse than that. If you make your code hard to read it's a disincentive to help. And if you walk eyes wide open into well-known traps, it's just kind of depressing.

Comment: Feel free to delete, but note that if you delete the question instead of fixing it the downvotes it has will count against question bans for something like the next six months.

Comment: Alrighty! Will keep that in mind!

Comment: If you have an answer you can give it here, that is really appreciated.

Comment: Just make sure that the answer could have been given by others, too. I.e. double check that the information needed for finding the answer is really given in the question. If the output formati is wrong, then you should probably show the output you get and compare it to the correct output. A good question (which has the information to be answered) in combination with a clear answer, is very upvotable, even if both is by yourself. No need to delete the question just because you know the answer now.

Comment: Ok! Here is the  [link](https://github.com/akrammohammed99/GoogleKickstart/blob/master/stablewalls.cpp) to the solution of the problem Google Kickstart Round C - Stable Wall. I have added comments for anyone who wants to understand it!